# Why should you give parameters names in function declaration?

Tags: c++

I know that ommiting the parameter name in a function is sometimes used to indicate that that parameter is potentially unused. But is there a good reason why one should names to the parameters in a header function declaration in the first place?

Why is

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

in any way better than

```
int sum(int, int);
```

or even (if you prefer the mathematical way)

```
auto sum(int, int) -> int; ?
```

In my opinion the first method just provides implemantation detail and should therefore not be exposed in the declaration. Not specifying the type even has the advantage of spotting missing abstraction. For example

```
auto max_element(iterator, iterator);
```

would be pretty weird, but naming them does not actually make it much better, as

```
auto max_element(range);
```

is what we actually want to express.

I would be interested in examples where the names actually add something and are not just missing abstraction.

Comment: For better readability, if some developer looks at the declaration.

Comment: `set_pixel(int, int, int)`: Is that x,y,z, or RGB?  Names can help there.

Comment: I would prefer set_pixel(Pixel), that is exactly the point with the abstraction.

Comment: I prefer descriptive names that tell you what the parameters are .

Comment: I omit them when they don't convey any additional information.  I provide them when they help the declaration be self-documenting.

Comment: @Henk OK, take a guess on that one `Image createRGBImage(int, int, bool, const Pixel*, size_t);`

Comment: Well, a function with 5 parameters with two consecutive of the same type should probably not exist in modern c++? There is definitely some missing abstraction.

Comment: @Henk Consecutive parameters of the same type can and do happen, and names can help disambiguate. Consider for example `string::substr(size_t, size_t)`, which, without names, would leave you guessing whether the second parameter is a position or a count.

Comment: But you would be guessing when seeing the function call (without IDE support), too. Why not use a range?

Comment: @Henk "*you would be guessing when seeing the function call*" That's a red herring. The way the declaration is written does not, and could possibly not, directly help with reading the code that is *using* the function. Just because adding names to the declaration does not solve every single problem everywhere doesn't mean it's useless.

Comment: That was the argument using ranges instead of your proposal. I agree that `string::substr(size_t, size_t)` is worse than giving parameter names, but I think that such a function does not exist in ideal modern c++ because it represents a range of numbers and should therefore be expressed like that.

Comment: @Henk [`std::string::substr(std::size_t position, std::size_t count)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is part of the Standard C++ Library, upto and including C++20.

Comment: Thankfully I am old enough that I don't need to worry about what will happen to C++ when Henk is old enough to be the head of the Standards Committee.

Comment: What you really seem to be asking is why don't people engineer distinct types for every parameter? Well many applications don't require that much engineering. It can get laboursome to have to create a class for all you minor components and creating primitive level types like that can lead to libraries being less interoperable with one another. How many definitions of "Point" are there? If using two libraries it can be useful to have `(int x, int y) variations for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function declarations describe the interface, i.e. how the function is meant to be used. Consider the following example:

```
void rotate(int x, int y);
```

as opposed to:

```
void rotate(int height, int width);
```

These declarations have the same number and type of parameters, but the semantics of the parameters are very different. Naming the parameters is a reasonable way of expressing this meaning.

---

Of course, one could make the argument that the function should be either:

```
void rotate(Point);
```

or

```
void rotate(Dimensions);
```

where both `Point` and `Dimensions` are simple `struct`s containing 2 `int`s. This approach does make naming the parameters in the declaration unnecessary.

While this is probably the better approach, this may not always be an option. For example, if you are working on a large code base that has many uses of such functions, this might require a lot of refactoring, and the cost of that might not be justified by the benefits.

For new code, I would personally recommend this approach, not just for the clear semantics in the declaration, but more for the added type safety provided by wrapping the arguments in a separate type.

---

There are pros and cons to both approaches, and which one you pick is an engineering and design decision that should be made based on the particular use case, and circumstances.

Comment: I think that one should definitely go for the abstraction here. The problem is that you do not see the parameter names when calling the function. Therefore having the same type twice with different meaning can lead to problems.

Comment: @Henk I agree, but that may not always be a viable option. I've expanded the answer a bit to point out why.

Comment: Yeah, valid point. That does not really apply to new code though, right?

Comment: @Henk No, it doesn't (IMO). I'll add that to the answer as well, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are some reasons (not necessarily good) to have named parameters in declarations:

- some tools like documentation generators, and intellisense use them.
- "documentation" of the function

  Types are not always sufficient, e.g. for `T clamp(T, T, T)` you might argue that extra type (such as a range, but then how do you declare range?) might replace the need for naming. It might be true for some cases, but it might not always be the case, e.g. `Person(std::string lastName, std::string firstName)` requires extra works (which might be not done by laziness :-/, or which might be seen as over-engineering (Creating class `LastName`, especially if used only a few times; Creating such classes for custom named parameter is mostly a more advanced way).
- ways to create the declarations (tools or manual copy/paste from definition).
- habits/guideline to follow

I personally omit/remove them (especially if they have same name as their type), except if they give meaning.

Comment: Thanks! So would you try to make the names redundant and then remove them?

Comment: I (try to) create classes when they make sense (to provide meaning, to avoid mistakes). So creating a class `LastName` seems to me over-engineering in general cases (as `Person` seems a more central class). You might still be in cases where you manipulate them a lot, and so it might make sense. So I don't try to make redundancy to remove them, but only remove redundancy when present.

Comment: Yeah, I would probably also create a `Person` class, but then I would think about having a struct `Name` within that class, that contains that information. What do you think about `using LastName = std::string;` ?

Comment: I dislike weak typedef for that, as it is not type-safe as it may look like (`void foo(FirstName, LastName); foo(LastName("Doe"), FirstName(John));` would compile :-/ (even if order is wrong)). strong typedef would be ok though.